# LinqDataSource throws System.Data.Linq.Mapping.DataAttribute is not defined error

Tags: vb.net, linq, linqdatasource

I am using an ASP.net Website project in VB.net and have added a LINQ to SQL data class to it in order to use a number of LinqDataSource controls.  Yesterday my project worked fine but after shutting down last night and starting up this morning I now get this error:

> Compilation Error Description: An error occurred during the
>   compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please
>   review the following specific error details and modify your source
>   code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: BC30002: Type 'System.Data.Linq.Mapping.DatabaseAttribute' is not defined.

**Source Error:**

```
<Global.System.Data.Linq.Mapping.DatabaseAttribute(Name:="xxxx_pcf")>  _
Partial Public Class PCFDataContext
    Inherits System.Data.Linq.DataContext
```

This file is auto-generated by Visual Studio 2010 but it throws no errors. I only get the error at runtime.

Elsewhere on the internet people have recommended removing the Namespace declaration, only I don't have one.

I also found [here](http://programmer.wrighton.org/2010/11/linq-to-sql-error-bc30002.html) somebody saying that the reference to `System.Data.Linq` might be missing from the web.config file.  Not for me though, my web.config is ok.

Also [here](http://akselsoft.blogspot.co.uk/2010/06/linq-reserved-names-and-net.html) a warning about VS renaming your classes for pluralization reasons - again not valid for me.

So I am stuck.

Comment: So it gets stranger... I renamed one of the Data Classes and re-ran the site - it worked.  As a test, I changed the name of the Data Class back to the original value - it still worked!  Whats going on?

Comment: This error re-occurred after deploying the site to the web server. There has to be a way to solve this - anyone?

Answer (score 6):

I had the similar issue when I used LINQtoSQL(vb.net) in my website(.net 4.0 framework) for the first and rolled it out to the live server. It was working fine in my local server.

All I did is adding the below lines in my web.config

```
<page>
 <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Data.Linq" />
    <add namespace="System.Linq" />
 </namespaces>
</Page>
<system.web>
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
     <add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
  </assemblies>
</system.web>
```

It worked for me,worth a try my friend...

Comment: This worked for me, but the structure is a little off. `<page>` should be `<pages>` and it should be nested under `<system.web>`. Also, `<assemblies>` should be nested under `<system.web><compilation>`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like its a problem with VB only and C# does not face the same issue. Have a look [here](http://stevescodingblog.co.uk/vb-dynamic-query-library-woes/). Hope it helps